# WMSgetFeatureInfo problem

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to get attributes of feature using getFeatureInfo:

```
if(sss==null){
   if (sld==null){
     sld= new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms', 
    title: 'Identify',
    layers: myLayer,
    queryVisible: true
     });
   app.mapPanel.map.addControl(sld);
   sss=app.mapPanel.map.getControlsBy('title', 'Identify');
}                                   
}
for(var i=0;i<sss.length;i++){
alert("BROMACIA");
 sss[i].activate();
}
sss[0].events.register("getfeatureinfo", app.mapPanel.map, function showInfo(evt) {
alert(evt.text)});
```

And nothing heppens.
When i try to do in firebug:

```
>>> sss[0].events.register("getfeatureinfo", app.mapPanel.map, function showInfo(evt) { alert(evt.text)});
```

firebug says `undifined`.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
if(sss==null){
if (sld==null){
 sld= new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms', 
title: 'Identify',
layers: myLayer,
queryVisible: true
 });
app.mapPanel.map.addControl(sld);
sss=app.mapPanel.map.getControlsBy('title', 'Identify');
}                                   
}
function showInfo(evt) {
lert(evt.text);
}
for(var i=0;i<sss.length;i++){
  alert("BROMACIA");
  sss[i].activate();
  sss[i].events.register("getfeatureinfo", app.mapPanel.map, showInfo);
}
```